cloud functions firebase to use it
Do I need a backend language for Firebase Cloud Functions, or is TypeScript enough to code, for example, a matchmaking system?
ChatGPT himself isn't sure about that.
Is it a fact that you don't need a backend language, or is it wrong?
Have a nice day, by the way.
I am good at Angular TypeScript, having built a large Slack clone alone in 4 months.

You can code Cloud Functions for Firebase in JavaScript/TypeScript or in Python. To get started, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
